# Checking answer for expectation and variance

Tags: probability

> $Y$ and $\{U_{r}:r\geqslant 1\}$ are independent random variables,
>   where $U_{i}$'s are continuous uniform random variables on $[0,1]$ and
>   $\mathbb{P}(Y=y)=\dfrac{1}{(e-1)y!}$, for $y=1,2,3,\dots$.
>
> Define $M=\max\left(U_{1},U_{2},...,U_{Y}\right)$.
>
> Find $\mathbb{E}(M)$ and $\text{Var}(M)$.

My thought:

First, I derived the CDF for $M$ as follows:
$$\begin{align}
F_{M}(t)&=\sum_{y=1}^{\infty }P(M\leq t|Y=y)P(Y=y) \\
&=\sum_{y=1 }^{\infty }\mathbb{P}\left(\max(U_{1},U_{2},...,U_{y}\right)\leq t)f_{Y}(y) \\
&=\sum_{y=1}^{\infty }\mathbb{P}(\max(U_{1}\leq t,U_{2}\leq t,...,U_{y}\leq t)f_{Y}(y) \\
&=\sum_{y=1}^{\infty }t^{y}\frac{1}{(e-1)y!} \\
&=\frac{1}{e-1}\sum_{y=1}^{\infty }\frac{t^{y}}{y!} \\
&=\frac{e^{t}-1}{e-1}
\end{align}$$

Therefore, the density function for $M$ is
$$f_{M}(t)=\frac{e^{t}}{e-1}$$
and
$$\begin{align}
&\mathbb{E}(M)=\int_{0}^{1}m\cdot \frac{e^{m}}{e-1} \text{ d}m=\frac{1}{e-1}\int_{0}^{1}me^{m}\text{ d}m=\frac{1}{e-1}\\
&\mathbb{E}(M^{2})=\int_{0}^{1}m^{2}\cdot \frac{e^{m}}{e-1} dm=\frac{1}{e-1}\int_{0}^{1}m^{2}e^{m}dm=\dfrac{e-2}{e-1}\text{.}\end{align}$$

Hence, $\text{Var}(M)=\mathbb{E}(M^{2})-[\mathbb{E}(M)]^{2}=\dfrac{1}{(e-1)^2}$.

I'm not sure about the result I got because a hint was given but I didn't use them at all. So I'm wondering if I missed something and got the wrong answer.

The hint is: $$\begin{align}
&\frac{x}{x+1}=1-\frac{1}{x+1} \\
&\frac{x}{x+2}=1-\frac{2}{x+2}\text{.}
\end{align}$$

Does anyone know where could the hint be applied when solving this problem? Or I solved the problem correctly and the hint just has nothing to do with my solution.

Thank you for your help!